# DeathWatchNotification when stopping parent actor

Tags: f#, akka.net, dead-letter

I have the following actor hierarchy:

[image: Actor hierarchy]

The `receiver` is responsible for handling HTTP requests. When a request comes this actor creates a child actor `coordinator` (actually with a dynamic name).

After the `coordinator` finishes its work it executes `Context.Stop(Self)`.
This gracefully stops all the children, but then I get the following messages in the console:

> [INFO][23.05.2016 08:48:45][Thread 0013][akka://FSharpSystem/user/receiver/$b] Message DeathWatchNotification from akka://FSharpSystem/user/receiver/$b to akka://FSharpSystem/user/receiver/$b was not delivered. 1 dead letters encountered.
>
> [INFO][23.05.2016 08:48:45][Thread 0013][akka://FSharpSystem/user/receiver/$b] Message DeathWatchNotification from akka://FSharpSystem/user/receiver/$b to akka://FSharpSystem/user/receiver/$b was not delivered. 2 dead letters encountered.
>
> [INFO][23.05.2016 08:48:45][Thread 0013][akka://FSharpSystem/user/receiver/$b] Message DeathWatchNotification from akka://FSharpSystem/user/receiver/$b to akka://FSharpSystem/user/receiver/$b was not delivered. 3 dead letters encountered.

Looks like all three actors send a `DeathWatchNotification` to the `coordinator` ($b is its dynamic name). I haven't subscribed to this notification and don't want to see it in the logs. How to disable this behavior (preferably in F#)?

P.S. Here is a [Gist with the sample code](https://gist.github.com/M0ns1gn0r/45ca2e0e22069c1ce38b394b235b0566).

Comment: +1 for the diagram, but you need to make it easier for people to help you.  Could you GitHub up a quick F# .fsx script to demo the issue?  I got to thinking about interactions between actors + considered doing the .fsx myself, but then thought, "perhaps you've already got a script."

Comment: @sgtz Added one, please see the P.S. section.